# How to get device from cdev

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver, dma

I am writing a kernel module that will allocate some coherent memory and return the corresponding virtual and physical addresses.

I am registering the module as `cdev`, allocating space with `dma_alloc_coherent()` and I wanted to mmap it using `dma_common_mmap()`.

`dma_common_mmap()` requires a pointer to `struct device`: how could I obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

```
void *dma_alloc_coherent(struct device *dev, size_t size, dma_addr_t *dma_handle, int flag);
```

This function handles both the allocation and the mapping of the buffer. The first two arguments are the device structure and the size of the buffer needed.
The function returns the result of the DMA mapping in two places. The return value from the function is a kernel virtual address for the buffer, which may be used by the driver.
The associated bus address, meanwhile, is returned in dma_handle.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get dma_alloc_coherent and mmap to work.  I cannot do this.  I had to write my own read/write functions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at
`int cdev_device_add(struct cdev *cdev, struct device *dev)`

You can find an working example at
`linux-source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c`