# dma_common_mmap documentation to let user read/write physical address

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, dma

I am trying to write a Linux kernel module to map some address back to the user using `dma_common_mmap()`. I then want the user to mmap and write/read the address space.

My main problem now is that I can't find the documentation for `dma_common_mmap()`, does any exist? I have googled but didn't find out how to use it and let the user read/write the address.

Comment: How tag `c++11` is related with Linux kernel module?

Comment: The user space code will be written in c++ 11, i.e. the mmap.

Comment: But the question is about kernel module, not about user space code, isn't it? Also, `mmap` is C function, not a c++. And using this function doesn't requre any special `C` standard - any C compiler should support it.

Comment: OK, I can take that away.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815099/how-to-get-device-from-cdev

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516847/what-is-the-difference-between-dma-mmap-coherent-and-remap-pfn-range

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896231/allocating-a-physical-memory-buffer-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `dma_common_mmap()` doesn't exist. But you can look at  Doxygen comment for `dma_mmap_attrs()` function:

```c
/**
 * dma_mmap_attrs - map a coherent DMA allocation into user space
 * @dev: valid struct device pointer, or NULL for ISA and EISA-like devices
 * @vma: vm_area_struct describing requested user mapping
 * @cpu_addr: kernel CPU-view address returned from dma_alloc_attrs
 * @handle: device-view address returned from dma_alloc_attrs
 * @size: size of memory originally requested in dma_alloc_attrs
 * @attrs: attributes of mapping properties requested in dma_alloc_attrs
 *
 * Map a coherent DMA buffer previously allocated by dma_alloc_attrs
 * into user space.  The coherent DMA buffer must not be freed by the
 * driver until the user space mapping has been released.
 */
static inline int
dma_mmap_attrs(struct device *dev, struct vm_area_struct *vma, void *cpu_addr,
           dma_addr_t dma_addr, size_t size, struct dma_attrs *attrs)
{
    struct dma_map_ops *ops = get_dma_ops(dev);
    BUG_ON(!ops);
    if (ops->mmap)
        return ops->mmap(dev, vma, cpu_addr, dma_addr, size, attrs);
    return dma_common_mmap(dev, vma, cpu_addr, dma_addr, size);
}

#define dma_mmap_coherent(d, v, c, h, s) dma_mmap_attrs(d, v, c, h, s, NULL)
```

`dma_mmap_attrs()` calls in turn `dma_common_mmap()`, so all the documentation (except for `attrs` param) applies to `dma_common_mmap()` as is.

### EDIT

I think you should use `dma_mmap_coherent()` (along with `dma_alloc_coherent()`), which does pretty much the same as `dma_common_mmap()` (see code above). See [this example](https://github.com/claudioscordino/mmap_alloc) to get some clue on how to use it both in kernel side and in user-space. See also how `dma_mmap_coherent()` is used in ALSA kernel code, in [snd_pcm_lib_default_mmap()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/core/pcm_native.c#L3380) function.

Comment: Thanks, I will learn by trial and error.  I wanted examples as I am having trouble making this work with mmap.  I had to write my own read and write functions.

Comment: @user1876942 I added **EDIT** section to my answer, providing you with some examples on how to use `dma_mmap_coherent()`, which is probably what you really want to use.